# Aligning input field to left of button toolbar in Bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to place my input field directly to the left of the 3 buttons (the `btn-toolbar`) on the right side. I'm not sure why this is so difficult. I have tried changing the width of the input field and using various utility classes without success. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
          <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
          <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Get Data</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="search" class="form-control"/>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
          <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col1</th>
          <th>Col2</th>
          <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from @k123, I was able to come up with a solution that seems to work okay. But if there is a better way to accomplish this, I'd be happy to choose a better answer.

I ended up putting the `form-group` into the last `div` and using the `pull-left` class to force it to the left of the buttons. It's definitely not the most ideal solution, but seems to look "well enough" on large displays.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
        <div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
        <div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
      <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Get Data</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 text-right">
      <div class="form-group pull-left">
        <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="search" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In one row your columns have to add up to 12 as it is a 12 column grid in Bootstrap. I have made the input 2 columns and the buttons 4 columns.

I have also fixed the mobile size layout by adding 3 cols of 4 followed 2 cols of 6 and adding a 'form group' class around the input field.

Updated to add 'text-right' to the button columns, and remove 'button-toolbar' from around the three buttons.

Updated again to add more breakpoints, so the large screen size looks better.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
          <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
          <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 text-right">
        <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Get Data</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-3 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
          <input type="search" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-right">
        <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Col1</th>
              <th>Col2</th>
              <th>Col3</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is better but the input field and buttons aren't lined up to the right edge of the table. They're now more toward the center.

Comment: I have updated the snippet to right align the buttons in their columns.

Comment: Yes, but now the input field is not aligned next to the buttons. :(

Comment: That's because the input is in a column on its own. Bootstrap 3 can't make columns adjust automatically to fit the space, but Bootstrap 4 can. Is it a requirement that you continue to use Bootstrap 3?

Comment: Yes, Bootstrap3 is a requirement because the rest of the application uses it and I can't migrate to Bootstrap4 at the moment.

Comment: Updated the answer by adding extra column breakpoints to make it look better at the larger screen size.